# I think my female map turtle is trying to lay her eggs in the water

Tags: aquarium, reptiles, breeding, turtles, freshwater

I have two map turtles; one male and another one female.

I caught them doing the mating dance and the deeds plenty of times. I got the male from a friend and he was lonely, so about a month later got the female from our local pet store. She was the only map turtle I could find.

Well, it's been about a year now and she has shown signs of trying to make nests in the dry area, as evidenced by the missing soil/sand. For about three weeks she has been hiding in the back of the water tank, not even coming up to bask like she normally does. On the other hand, the male kept the normal routine. Now she is swimming all over the tank up and down all crazy non-stop for two days. Also, as a note - she has a pea-sized opening at the base of her tail but I see no egg.

What should I do? Any information would be great, thanks.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: Look [here](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/25314/my-female-red-eared-slider-as-far-as-im-guessing-is-gravid) and [here](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/18912/red-eared-slider-laying-eggs-into-the-water) to get more information about female turtles are gravid and may be laying her eggs into the water.